# Exporting RSA containers key container across domain

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, web-config, rsa

I need to create a RSA container, export it and use it on a private machine and and on a machine that is part of a domain.

Why  - encrypting web.config file of my ASP.NET app, so that I am able to run it on these machines. Solution to this would be to just not share the web.config file, encrypt them on each o the machines separately, but that would lead to duplicity and every downside that comes with that.

I was following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/2w117ede(v=vs.100)) walkthrough. And got stuck at adding access rights to the key.

My question is: Is this even possible?

I was thinking of something like creating the key on the domain machine and than using a VPN/"run program as" to run it as the domain user. While trying this, I ran into some issues, but I did not give it enough time.

Is there another / better way? Help highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the domain you're publishing it to have AD Certificate Services?

Comment: @JustinCervero Propably yes, but there is no way that I am getting a hold of them.

Comment: I missed the part where you said you wanted to run in on both a domain machine and a non-domain machine. The part you describe about 'run as' probably won't work. The non-domain machine can run the process but will likely be problematic. I think the instructions you were following should work you just need to grant the non-domain account rights to access the key you import.